# Does Hasura (GraphQL) supports multiple databases?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I am implementing a GraphQL server ([Hasura](https://hasura.io/)), the normal setup looks like this:

```
docker run -d --net=host \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@hostname:port/dbname \
-e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

I couldn't find in the [docs](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/docker/index.html#) a way to use multiple databases within the same instance, is it even possible?

Comment: It's not possible.  Each Hasura engine can connect to only one database at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hasura added that feature recently to Hasura 2.0 . By now you can use multiple databases per hasura instance

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible.

If you want one graphql endpoint, you can instantiate many Hasura as you need for each tables. One of this Hasura instance could be your main endpoint, and you can add remote schema for each other tables.